# Running rsync reduces available space on source disk

Tags: rsync

I am backing up a home server in order to reinstall it, and I'm using rsync to backup the whole filesystem tree. This is the rsync command I'm using:

```
rsync -aAXH --info=progress2 --exclude=dev/ --exclude=proc/ --exclude=sys/ --exclude=tmp/ --exclude=run/ --exclude=mnt/ --exclude=media/ --exclude=lost+found --exclude=srv/ / /srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/backup/pensieroprofondo/debian10/btrfs/
```

To clarify: everything in `/` is on the same disk (although in different partitions) except `/srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/`, which resides on a different disk.

The root filesystem is installed on a small SSD (128 GB), which was 60-70% full before this operation (I can't remember exactly). The disk has been that full for the last couple of years and I haven't done anything different in the last couple of days, except running the rsync command do back it up. Now the system disk is completely full (`df -h` reports 108G out of 111G used) and as such it's become kind of unusable (nginx is throwing an internal server error for example) and running the rsync command again fails (it doesn't really throw an error but it exits with a progress of 0%). At least I can still ssh into it.

I haven't had a chance to reboot it yet, to see if that may clear up some space, but regardless I don't think this is the expected behaviour for what I'm done. Why is rsync eating up 30-40% of the source disk space? If it can help, I was running the rsync command inside a screen session.

Comment: The `rsync` command you've shown us isn't writing to the root filesystem, so it can't be the culprit filling it up

Comment: @ChrisDavies I would agree with you, but it's the only thing that I've been running differently for a long time. Disk space was ok before running the command, and it was not ok after running the command. When I launched it I didn't touch anything else, I just disconnected from the screen session and disconnected from the server via ssh. It literally can't be anything else.

Comment: Do you have a growing swapfile on the ssd? `rsync -H` requires it to keep a list of hardlinks in memory; if you have many it might take up a lot of ram or swap.

Comment: no, I don't. I have 16 GB or RAM and another 16 GB of swap partition on a different disk. BTW, I rebooted the server but it didn't free up the space. If it was in swap it would have freed it, right? Anyway, I deleted some bigger files and I got it back running to finish the backup. Still, it would be nice to figure out what's going on.